# C# WPF MVVM - evaluate ComboBox value after focus is lost

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm trying to read a number in a TextBox which is odd, positive and greater than 1.
I tried to achieve the binding set property to handle this logic but the problem is that set{} of the property is called every time a new character is typed. (You may see the problem here ... I cannot start typing an odd number which starts with 1, like 13, or starts with an even digit, like 23. I can do so if I type 3 then move cursor in front of it and type 1 for example) So I was thinking to raise the set{} of the property only when the focus is lost. I'm not very familiar with LostFocus event and I'm not even sure if this is the best approach.
Here is my code, maybe someone can tweak it so I can get the right functionality.
Code has the behavior I just explained above.

in View Class - XAML

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,5,0">
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="SmoothWinSize" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <ExceptionValidationRule />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

in ViewModel Class:

```
#region Smooth Windows Size

private string smoothWinSize = null;
private int sws;
public string SmoothWinSize
{
    get { return smoothWinSize; }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            // Assures that we accept only digits
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^(^$|(?:[1-9]\d*)|(?:(?=[\d.]+)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)\.\d+))$"))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Please enter a positive, odd and greater than 1 number.");
            }

            if (value != "")
            {
                sws = Int32.Parse(value);
                if (sws % 2 != 1 || sws <= 1)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Please enter a positive, odd and greater than 1 number.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                value = null;
            }

            smoothWinSize = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SmoothWinSize");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Did you try the obvious `UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"`?

Comment: no xD ... Ill try it now ... totally forgot about that. Give me a sec :)

Comment: I guess its working :), I feel embarrassed... how could I miss that :/ !!! ... thx a lot :D